# Influx:Show field keys based on tag values (or the other way)

Tags: fields, influx-db

I have an influx database with one tag key (called machine) and multiple field key (called cpu and memory). I want to be able to find all unique tag values for each field key or filled field keys for a given tag value.

Here is an example of database:

```
SELECT * FROM "myMeasurement"

name: myMeasurement
-------------------
time                   machine     cpu     memory
2020-01-01T00:00:00Z   m1          51
2020-01-01T01:00:00Z   m2                  2048
2020-01-01T00:00:00Z   m1          52
2020-01-01T01:00:00Z   m2                  2054
```

I would like to retrieve **m1** when requesting machine containing **cpu** values and/or **cpu** when requesting not empty field keys for machine **m1**.

Thanks